# Current working directory is not a cordova based project

Tags: cordova, camera

While adding the plugin for cordova camera api i am executing the command 
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
but after executin it getting error in cmd like 'Current working directory is not cordovo based project'
did i missed somethig?
need help.
thank you.

Comment: you need to run the cordova command within the project that you have created with cordova. e.g $`cordova create myproject com.myproject myproject`. Then do $`cd myproject` and then run the plugin add command in the myproject i.e $cordova plugin add ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not mentioned how you did create the project and for which environment you are trying to add the plugin.

**Common steps are:**

1. Create a project

   **$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld**
2. go inside of the newly created project folder i.e. hello in this case

   **$ cd hello**
3. Now add your desired platform(s)

   **$ cordova platform add android**
4. Once a platform has been added, now you can add any plugin.

   **$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera**

**NOTE:** The **CLI** **adds** plugin code as **appropriate for each platform**. If you want to develop with lower-level shell tools or platform SDKs , you need to run the Plugman utility to add plugins separately for each platform. (For more information, see [Using Plugman to Manage Plugins](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/plugin_ref_plugman.md.html#Using%20Plugman%20to%20Manage%20Plugins).)

Comment: Thank you for steps..refering to your answer achieved required.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error in my android project, this is how I solved it:

1. Create new cordova project `cordova create app`
2. add android platform by `cordova platform add android`
3. Copy the full application folder that we are using in the newly
   created     project/platform folder
4. Copy the all cordova files from platform/android folder to the
   application folder
5. Delete the android folder
6. Rename the application folder to android
7. import the android folder in android studio
8. Build and run the project

I hope anyone who is facing the same issue would be solved.
I know its too late to post but hope anyone can get help.

**P.S**- I have not used any plugin, so if you are using plugin then you have to add them also

Answer (score 0):

With my existing project i just created .cordova folder, using `mkdir .cordova` and that worked for me.